# aligning column headers in gt (r)

Tags: r, gt

The following piece of code produces a table with the header of the first column centered.
It should be left aligned. I have not found a way of changing the alignment for just this header. Can it be done?

The culprit seems to be `tab_spanner`. If that is omitted, alignment works.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_df <- structure(list(Bundesland = c("Burgenland", "Kärnten", "Niederösterreich"
), `Positiv M` = c(4065, 4814, 4114), `Positiv W` = c(4013, 5222, 
4128), `Verstorben M` = c(82, 131, 76), `Verstorben W` = c(70, 
115, 69)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

my_df  %>%
gt() %>%
  fmt_number(columns=2:5,decimals = 0,
             sep_mark = ".",dec_mark = ",") %>%
  tab_spanner("pro 100.000",2:5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a recent bug that was patched, and you can use the following after installing the dev version: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/607

```
library(devtools)

devtools::install_github('rstudio/gt')

my_df  %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_number(columns=2:5,decimals = 0,
             sep_mark = ".",dec_mark = ",") %>%
  cols_align(columns = 1,
             align = "left") %>% 
  tab_spanner("pro 100.000",2:5)
```

Assuming this is your expected result:

[image]

Comment: Fixes the problem but does not address the question of whether the column headers can be aligned differently to the body's alignments ?